# Minimum length of concrete fasteners to floor and ceiling to attach a wall?

Tags: concrete, walls, fastener

I want to attach a wall, of 7-9.2cm thickness, on ceiling and floor. Drywall with wood frame done for living  apartment in a block of flat: 42mm x 66mm woods form the wood frame where 13mm drywalls attached on both sides. Some wood frames are 70mm thick while others 92mm.

Recommedations conflict for fasteners: 120mm fine, 120mm too long, 100mm good -- not wanting fastener to go into neighbour side in a block of flat. The fasteners are needed to be attached to the floor and ceiling. The floor and ceiling are concrete.

How to determine the minimum length for a concrete fastener to build a wall?

Comment: Well - how thick is the wall?

Comment: @brhans the thickness is 7cm. The fasteners will be attached to the floor and the ceiling.

Comment: What is the new wall made of? Wood frame + drywall?

Comment: @manassehkatz yes wood frame with drywall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to think about what you need from the fasteners:

- shear strength
- pullout strength

Then you have to think about what you have to anchor into:

- thickness of concrete in floors and ceilings
- strength (PSI rating) of concrete

Then you can select an anchor / fastener with the strength you need, given the embedment possible and the strength of the concrete.

For this application, I'd bet that 1/2" expansion anchors or drop-in anchors would work, they require 2" embedment (about 5 cm).

Comment: Expansion anchors are way overkill for positioning a wall (unless there's massive shelf loading planned).

Answer (score 0):

Since the screws are mostly providing lateral stability, and since they're going into concrete, penetration of 2cm should do. 3cm is probably ideal. That said, you haven't told us anything about the wall or its purpose. This is general advice.

Comment: Wood frame with drywall. 42mm lower wood of wood frame needed to be penerated to fasten the new wall to concrete floor. 42mm upper wood and then the vertical woods form the frame where you attach the drywall. Purpose: new archtecture so new walls needed in a living apartment (renovating).

Comment: If I attach 100mm fasteners, they will penetrate about 58mm into the concrete at most (100mm-42mm). 120mm would penetrate 78mm, too much? I have got two local  recommendations: 100mm and 120mm.

Comment: "Lower wood" and "upper wood" are "wall plates" (bottom and top, respectively).

Comment: That's up to you. How much drilling do you want to do? Concrete screws can be finicky, and driving them deeper than necessary doesn't help things.